# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error ,Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java

[image]

Error Page ScreenShot. And the Selected Text is the error.

Answer (score 5):

The `System` class starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

Java is case-sensitive. The `System` class (`java.lang.System`) starts with a capital S.